# error: storage class specified for parameter

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int recursive(static int a,static int b){
    static int c = 100;
    if(c != 105){
        c++;
        a++;
        b++;
        recursive(a,b);
        printf("\n a : %d b : %d \n",a,b);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(){
    int a = 10;
    int b = 1;
    recursive(a,b);
}
```

Getting compilation error as below :

```
error: storage class specified for parameter ‘a’
error: storage class specified for parameter ‘b’
```

Why can't we declare the functions parameters as static. The above program when passed with parameters as `int`, compiles fine and gives the expected output.

Comment: What would it mean for the parameters to be `static`?

Comment: What could it possibly mean for a function parameter to be `static`?

Comment: Your question's unclear. You have to explain what is your intended effect of declaring function parameters as `static`. What would it achieve? What output would you expect from the above program with `static` parameters? It is really completely non-intuitive.

Comment: Note that C99 and C11 allow `static` in the array dimensions in the parameter list of a function, a moderately peculiar reuse of the keyword `static`.  See sections 6.7.6.2 and 6.7.6.3 of the C11 standard. It does not allow `static` to be attached to array dimensions in other places, nor does it allow `static` to be used as the storage class for function parameters.

Answer (score 4):

The only storage class specifier come up with function parameters is `register`.

#### C11: 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes):

> The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is `register`.

Comment: It is pretty much useless nowadays, is it not? And deprecated in C++.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin; Yes.

Comment: Most compilers allow `register` storage class to be used only with `int` or `char` data_type.

Answer (score 2):

> Why cant we declare the functions parameters as static.

Function arguments have the same storage class as that of local variables.

This is why they can only ever have automatic (on-the-stack) storage class.

They can also have `register` storage duration, however, this is just a non-binding  optimization hint for the compiler.

Comment: They're most likely passed in registers here.

Comment: @DanielFischer This depends on the calling conventions of the compiler and platform. See [Calling conventions for different C++ compilers and operating systems](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf).

Comment: Most compilers allow `register` storage class to be used only with `int` or `char` data_type.